# A native way of adding custom JavaScript functions into a method-calls chain

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I would like to known if there is a native way of doing this :

```
Object.prototype.chain = function(f) { return f.call(this) }


function fun1() {
    doSomethingWithObject(this)
    return this
}

function fun2() {
    doSomethingElse(this)
    return this
}

someObject
    .method1('something')
    .method2()
    .chain(checkSomething() ? fun1 : fun2)
    .method3()
```

But I do not feel like changing the prototype of `Object`. Is there a way to do this without modifying the prototype of `Objects` or the other constructors that I use (and am not the developer of)

Edits :

I feel I do not explain very well, so let' add some details :

What I would like to do is to use some APIs I do not define. `someObject` is defined like the following, with chainable methods :

```
var someObject = {
    method1: function(val) {
        // do something
        return this
    },
    method2: function() {
        // do something
        return this
    },
    method3: function() {
        // do something
        return this
    }
}
```

Now imagine I cannot change this code, because this object is from a library, and so I don't want to. Then, imagine that I would like to chain methods and some custom functions (see my first snippet) for many more different objects. The simplest thing to do is to attach a `chain` method to `Object.prototype`.

But I think that it could result in conflicts in the future. I am looking for a way to do the same thing without touching the prototype.

Comment: what do you mean for neative?

Comment: I mean not touching the Object.prototype. I'm looking for a javascript already available on all javascript objects

Comment: Well, as long as the function is part of the original object (`myObject`) and the function returns `myObject` (`return this`, usually) upon its completion, you can chain-call another function. Otherwise I'd say - don't do this. You will find that it does not bring anything useful.

Comment: You mean method chaining, you do not have to change Object's prototype, why not making your own object and returing this within each setter method?

Comment: Do you want to do just method chain or function chain.  What I mean is do you want to be able to chain any function not only methods

Comment: Yes, I want to be abble to chain any function between two method calls from objects I do not implement. I know how to support chaining with my own objetcs since it simply consists in returning `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper is something that will wrap any object to make it compatible with "chaining" and will add another chain method that will allow you to plug external functions and still get the chaining.

Check this example:

```
   function myObj() {
    this.state = {
        a: 1
    };
    this.method1 = function () {
        console.log("1");
    }
    this.method2 = function () {
        console.log("2");
    }
    this.method3 = function () {
        console.log("3");
    }
    this.method4 = function () {
        console.log(this.state);
    }
}

function objectChainWrapper(obj) {
    this.chain = function (fn) {
        fn.call(obj);
        return this;
    }

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] == 'function') {
            this[prop] = (function (methodName) {
                return function () {
                    obj[methodName].call(obj);
                    return this;
                }
            }(prop))
        }
    }
}

var obj = new myObj();
var wrapper = new objectChainWrapper(obj);
var chainMethod = function(){ console.log('chain') };
var chainMethodState = function(){ console.log(this.state) };
wrapper.method1().method2().chain(chainMethodState).method3().chain(chainMethod).method4();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0qmteo7n/).

Comment: Is there a reason for the wrapper? I mean if the functions returned 'this' then you wouldn't need to use a wrapper you could just use the chain straight from the function. So in the end your chain would look like:

`myObj.method1().method2().method3();`

Essentially, all the wrapper is doing is adding "return this" to each function anyway.

Comment: @Jay - the wrapper takes an object and "rewrites" its methods so they will return "this" and allow chaining. Its a nice way to log or to modify your objects methods without modifying your objects.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your anwser ! As i would like to insert custom functions in the call chain, I don't think your code could allow it. But actually I could wrap the object first and add the `chain` method to the decoirator. Good point

Comment: @niahoo - I don't see why you want to call chain(method).method3() over calling method().method3().

Comment: Because I do not pass a method to chain, I pass a function I define myself, that the API does not implement by itself, and that must fit into a chain :)

Comment: @niahoo - Isn't that function already on the object you created?

Comment: No, it's not. Look at `chain(checkSomething() ? fun1 : fun2)`

Comment: @niahoo -  Check my edit. I've added functionality that will let you plug external functions as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised there are no answers to this to be honest.

There are many ways to natively introduce chaining. I like to use the [revealing module pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/).

So I create a basic model (Go ahead and chuck this in your chrome of firefox console)

```
var Dog = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;


     var core = {
            getName:function(){
                return self.name;
            }
        }; 

    this.movement = function(){     //this function will be exposed including its returned functions for chaining      
        console.log(self.name + " is getting restless... ");

        var jump = function(){
            console.log(self.name + " jumps around ");
            return this //returns the movement scope
        };
        var run = function(){
            console.log(self.name + " has decided to run");
            return this //returns the movement scope
        };

        return {
            jump:jump,
            run:run           
        };

    }       
    console.log("A Pup has been born, we shall call him... " + name);
    return{
        movement:self.movement    //only .movement is exposed to the outside world
    };
    }
```

Now create a new dog using `var p = new Dog("doggyName");`

now, you can chain functions. Try:

```
p.movement().jump().run().jump().run();
```

You should get the console logged text that corresponds with each function.

By returning the scope of this after executing your movement function you expose the additional functions that are returned in that scope (see the comments in the code). These can then be chained onto the end of your current function provided they are in the same scope. This allows you to scope specific parts of your code. For example with this dog, all movement is scoped to `self.movement`, you could have all eating scoped to `self.eat` and so on

[Read up on the revealing module pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/). Though this is not the only way to do it.

Comment: This is helpful. Interested to know other ways as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I wrote some edits to my question as I think it wasn't well written. Your example is interesting, I use this pattern (but didn't know the name, thanks) but it does not allow to introduce custom functions in the chain

Answer (score 2):

To "plug" an unbound function into the object's method chain you can assign it to  a property and call that:

```js
function fn() {
    document.write('hi ');
    return this;
}

someObj = {
    meth1: function() {
        document.write('meth1 ');
        return this;
    },
    meth2: function() {
        document.write('meth2 ');
        return this;
    }
}

someObj
    .meth1()
    [someObj._=fn, '_']()
    .meth2()
```

This doesn't look very pretty if you ask me. A more readable option is to add the `chain` method on the fly, like:

```
function chainable(obj) {
    obj.chain = function(fn) {
        return fn.call(this);
    }
    return obj;
}

chainable(someObj).meth1().chain(fn).meth2()
```

Comment: I like this technique also. I'm not too keen on having to call chain() after every function though. Like I said, there are loads of ways to do it, this way is much neater then the revealing module way :)

Comment: @Jay: from my understanding, the question is specifically about chaining of unbound functions, not chaining in general (which the asker seems to be well aware of).

Comment: I apologies, I thought the question was with regards to native chaining of JavaScript functions without using prototype. I'll take my leave.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It could be a good solution for me :] I'll still wait for other answers because I would like not to change the objects, but this is nice.